# Deflate Buffer using no compression mode

Tags: node.js, compression, buffer, deflate

Anyone know how to deflate a buffer using `zlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION`? The problem is that I don't know where and how to use the `Z_NO_COMPRESSION` option. Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
const zlib = require('zlib');
zlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION
zlib.deflate(stateInputs, function(err, res) {
    var fileOutput = Buffer.concat([bHeader,res]);
    fs.writeFile("./out.dat", fileOutput, function(err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an [`options` object](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_options) to [`deflate()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_deflate_buf_options_callback). One of these options is `level` which is where you'd set the compression level:

```
zlib.deflate(stateInputs, {
  level: zlib.Z_NO_COMPRESSION
}, function(err, res) {
 // ...
});
```